# Generating certain sequence of numbers with defined ranges

Tags: vb.net

How can I use a collection of nested for loops (or any other type) to produce a sequence like this with these variables:

`length` is how many digts to go to
`max` is the maximum number
`min` is the minimum number

Lets say for this case:

```
length = 2
max = 3
min = 1
```

it would produce:

```
11
12
13
21
22
23
31
32
33
```

This works "ok" for only length = 1, but not really, since I still have annoying 0's at the start

```
For i = 1 To length
For ii = 0 To i
For iii = 1 To 5
Console.WriteLine(Str(ii) + Str(iii))
Next
Next
Next
```

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: Dat homework problem :X!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! I tried to provide a more descriptive title. Please feel free to edit it if I've failed to capture the essence of your question. Also, please provide some sample code showing what you've tried so far and an explanation as to why it isn't working.

Comment: Where should the result be placed?

Comment: @Ruben Console window would be fine since he didn't specify anything.

Comment: Yep, the console window :)
I was just wondering if there was a possible algorithm for it.
Also, sorry for syntax issues and formatting and such. Still a noob at this website xD

Comment: Do you need the result to be a collection of integers, or a collection of strings?

Comment: Ermm, Strings I guess. Do you mean either 11 as in, eleven or 11 as in "11"

Comment: I have a solution, but its not optimised at all. Am I allowed to make another question? It would be easier to get across my ideas, lol :)

Answer (score 2):

*As this looks like a homework problem, I am going to attempt to help you think through this problem without actually giving you the answer in code.*

Let's think through this problem...

You have the range 1-3. So your first sequence is easy:

> 1, 2, 3

Now you want to produce a sequence from 11 to 13. What's the change, or difference, between 1 through 3 and 11 through 13? The answer is you've added 10.

The same is true for 21 through 23 - you've added 10 again.

So, what you want to do is iterate from 1 through 3.
Then, iterate from 1 through 3 this time adding 10.
Then, iterate from 1 through 3 this time adding 20.

Thinking about this, you are essentially doing this:

```
1
2
3
10 + 1
10 + 2
10 + 3
10 + 10 + 1
10 + 10 + 2
10 + 10 + 3
etc
```

Or, you could also think about it like this:

```
(0 * 10) + 1
(0 * 10) + 2
(0 * 10) + 3
(1 * 10) + 1
(1 * 10) + 2
(1 * 10) + 3
(2 * 10) + 1
(2 * 10) + 2
(2 * 10) + 3
etc
```

Can you see a pattern forming?

Comment: I.. can :'D
This isnt a homework problem as such. What im trying to do is have min and max as 32 and 126, then transfer these to characters based on their ASCII codes.
So it goes:
aa
ab
ac...

Comment: @TonyCantone - OK. We do get homework problems on here every now and then, so we try to help students rather than help them cheat. :)

Comment: @TonyCantone - Working with Excel, perhaps?

Comment: :) Your code works well. Now can/will I use the same method for length = 3? So after 33 it will go 111, 112, 113, 121...
When I say "the same method" I mean writing the numbers out and thinking logically about it :P

Comment: Ah, wait. Ive just thought of something. Ive been going about this all wrong *facepalm*. Ive actually just discovered that I just need the possibilities for the given length. So length = 1 would produce 1,2,3.
length = 2 would produce 11,12,13,21...
Thus the singe characters are not needed

Comment: I could do this with a Select Case as the number of nested for loops = length. Id like to know if this is possible just with one code block. Any ideas? :)